# C# Change System Location programmatically then reboot

Tags: c#

I have a need to completely change the systems location and apply it to all accounts.

I now how to change threads but in this case I need to actually change the system location for all user accounts.

It will be a device running windows that will have a windows service that when it starts up will make a web service call back to a centrally hosted system that will tell it it's configuration including it's location. It then needs to change it's location (applying to all user accounts) and then reboot itself.

I know how to do this from the control panel but I need to pragmatically do it in C#

Comment: Do you mean the locale, as in language setting?

Comment: If you open up (in Windows 7) control panel and click on Clock, Language and Region, then click on change location that drop down there.  Further you have to go to the administrative tab and click on change system locale...

Then above that there is a Copy settings to copy the change to system accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current user's geographical language by calling [SetUserGeoID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And you can set a user's locale by calling [SetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, that's just for the user account that is running the current program.

You'll need to use P/Invoke to call those methods. There might be prototypes and examples at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/).

For copying to other users, I'm not sure. Sounds like something you'd do with WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).

Comment: Thanks I have actually looked at SetLocaleInfo and SetUserGeoID.  The most important part though it changing it system wide not just the current logged in user.  The issue we have is when we image the devices we don't know in advanced where they will be going so we need to programatically change them once they arrive at their destination.

Answer (score 0):

All settings are included in registry. [HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International] location. So you may change them in C# and reboot the system.

Comment: That looks like I would have to update every individual setting not just one Change from US to UK.  And then that's just for default so existing system/user accounts would not get updated.